# -bash: jupyter: command not found (Mac OSx High Sierra 10.13)

Tags: python, bash, macos, python-2.7

Looking for some direction on what's going on with my path variable & why jupyter notebook won't run. I just bought a new laptop (Mac, Sierra 10.13), used pip to install jupyter, and am using Python 2.7 that comes already installed.

When I try to enter the command 'jupyter notebook', I get: 
`-bash: jupyter: command not found`

There is a 'jupyter' script located in '/Library/Python/2.7/lib/bin' and my PATH is set to the same in bash_profile. When I type 'echo $PATH', it returns:
`/Library/Python/2.7/lib/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin`

The only way I can get the jupyter notebook interface up & running is by entering 'python -m "jupyter" notebook' in terminal.

I have a feeling there is something wrong with where my packages are installed, but cannot figure it out. Happy to provide more information if someone can help. Thank you!

Comment: is the `jupyter` scipt executable (check with `ls -al /Library/Python/2.7/lib/bin`, check if there is a `x` in the permissions) ? Is it called `jupyter` or `jupyter.py` ?

Comment: Might want to look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35848096/jupyter-install-fails-on-mac which basically says you should download Python 2.7 which has updated packages to use Jupyter.

Comment: @A.J.Alger that worked, thank you!